# Command-C in vim on macOS is not copying even with "+clipboard" flag

Tags: copy-paste, vi, macvim

Let's take a look at the *clipboard* flags:

```
vim --version | grep clip
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
```

Looks ok to me ..  Highlighting some text in `vim` *does* turn on `Visual` mode. But then hitting <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> results in an annoyed "beep" and nothing more than that.

So I added the following to the default `.vimrc`

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Still no dice.  What needs to be done?

**Update**. `+y` does work.. but I've seen <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> work on other mac laptops i've owned. The last one right here (that does work) did not have anything special done afaict: there's not even any `~/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My confusion stems from "which" *terminal* is being used. I had not installed *iTerm2* yet: and *that* is the critical difference between the two laptops. With *mouse reporting* enabled we do have the desired `CMD-C` for copying text.  For plain old *terminal* there are various options to get the functionality of copying but I did not see any for `CMD-C`.  I settled for `+y` to yank the content.

Answer (score 1):

I had an iTerm2 Copy Paste issue while working in NeoVim (nvim).

I had the option *Enable Mouse Reporting* checked and that messed up my ability to use <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in Neovim.

To fix it:

- iTerm2 -> Setting (or ⌘-,)
- Search for *Enable Mouse Reporting*
- Uncheck